# Unknown subdomains pointing to my domain name

Tags: domains, dns, subdomain, security

About 6 months ago I purchased the domain name `example.net`. Today I was trying to go to my control panel at `example.net/cpanel` but accidentally went to `cpanel.example.net`. I found a completely different website at this sub domain. It seems to be some sort of gaming website that sells hardware as well. This sub domain does not show up in my cPanel and when I try to create the subdomain `cpanel.example.com` I get an error.

**Update:** I used a DNS zone editor to delete some `A` records that had been made to that subdomain. There were others including `mail.example.net`, `webmail.example.net` and `whs.example.net` all containing the same site. I have the issue of their existence solved, but I need to know if this is a breach in security. All of the subdomains seemed to have been named to purposely avoid suspicious. Does this sound like a breach in security?

Comment: Some web hosts and registrars do this automatically and I am not sure why. It is unwise. But I am not sure that it is a security risk by default, though I am sure it can be in some situations.

Comment: Could it be left behind from someone who previously owned the domain name?

Comment: I seriously doubt it. This is fairly common. Unfortunately.

Comment: I assume the `.com` is a slip?

Comment: @DylanHaynes It would help to clarify what w3d asked. The `A` records should probably be `CNAME` records that point to your host, not the IP address as w3d pointed out. It's probably just an oversight in your hosting company's DNS Zone Template, which you should relay to their support team.

Comment: If you bought the domain from someone, and not as a new domain, then they were probably still pointing to the guys server. If you two didn't use the same domain retailer, it's possible the A records got mixed up somewhere along the way.

Comment: @dan Not sure if you know, some DNS do not handle CNAMEs well so in some cases sub-domains can be defined using an A record by default. This is rare of course and not the norm. But still common enough.

Comment: @closetnoc Yep, `www` is a common one. On a shared host with control panels like cPanel, the "default" site is usually the first one, unless another one is selected, so if you use an `A` record for the subdomain, it will point to the default site for the IP address. I see this a lot when the Default DNS Template has been improperly modified.

Comment: @dan Part of that is an Apache thing. I always create a blank site on any web server as a catch-all site. This would be the first site created and like you said for some control panels this is somewhat automatic in how things are handled. I use the first site to trap all IP only references and deep-six them or redirect them or offer something different- whichever I prefer. Sometimes that is by time of day or mood. ;-) If the sun is bright and coffee is particularly good, I might redirect them to Disney. But the donuts have to be fresh!!

Answer (score 3):

It is common for webhosts to direct both `example.com/cpanel` and `cpanel.example.com` to your cPanel (on port 80 - not secure - better to use cPanel via HTTPS on port 2083). However, it seems they might not have set up the *redirection* for the subdomain and instead it's simply defaulting to the IP address of your *shared* server. In which case it is likely returning the first defined virtualhost, which seems to be this "gaming website". The webhost should really make sure that the first "host" returns some default server page or something equally meaningless.

Access your site by its IP address and you'll probably get the same "gaming website".

The other subdomains you mention are again fairly standard, as closetnoc mentions, although `webmail.` should really direct to your webmail service - but I presume it does not?! In your case *everything* is probably all on the same server, so `mail.` is probably just an alias for your servers IP address. `mail.` is often used with email clients for your incoming/outgoing mailserver, but you can probably just use your domain name (however, this is again the insecure way).