# My subdomains point to another website

Tags: domains, subdomain, shared-hosting

While testing some stuff on one of my subdomains I noticed it was pointing to another website. Unfortunately this is happening with all my subdomains.

To give out an example, let's say I have the `www.example.com` domain and the `mysubdomain.example.com`.

If I go to `mysubdomain.example.com` it points to my page, as it should, but it displays another fav icon, belonging to another website.

If however I go to `mysubdomain.example.com/index.html` (or `.php`), it points to another website. And by points I mean the website displayed appears as if it belongs to that web address, not redirecting.

Any thoughts?

I found this while searching for an explanation but my case it's a little different: [Unknown subdomains pointing to my domain name](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/77041/unknown-subdomains-pointing-to-my-domain-name).

However, it seams weird to me. Also, will this affect my bandwidth or pose a security risk in any way? Is there anyway I can, if not disabling this entirely, at least make sure someone else doesn't end up to that other website instead of mine?

Comment: Sounds like you're on shared hosting, and VirtualHosts aren't being created for your subdomains. Basically your server has multiple websites served from the same IP address, but the server needs to be setup to serve up different content based on the domain/subdomain being requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're on a shared host and haven't setup a subdomain but have setup a wildcard in your DNS so it points to your IP and it belongs to a server with multiple websites, it will point to the first VirtualHost in the Apache configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to delete wildcard `A record` in your DNS.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I went in touch with support and they helped me to solve the problem.